# Why aspectraio is not working in flexbox children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

HTML Part

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="card">hi</div>
 </div>
```

CSS Part

```
.container{
    width: 500px;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    margin: auto;
    
    display: flex;
    gap: 50px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    background: rgba(0, 1000, 0, 0.1);
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.card{
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    width: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 1000, 0, 0.1);
}
```

With the above code I expect that the `card` should be a squre of 50px. But surprisingly its height becomes 500px. i.e. same as the parent.

Please explain why it is happning.

If I remove the `display: flex;` from the `container` then the `card` becomes perfect squre as expected.

Comment: Have you tried adding `align-items: start` on your container.

Answer (score 3):

Why it's happening: the default value of `align-content` and `align-items` is `stretch`. `align-content: stretch` makes the flex line fill the flex container's cross size (cross size is height in your example because it is a row flexbox). Then `align-items: stretch` makes `.card`'s cross size fill the line's cross size, which was just stretched to be the container's cross size.

See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#valdef-align-items-stretch. It says "If the cross size property of the flex item computes to auto [then stretch]."

The purpose of that condition is so that stretching doesn't override a specified cross size on the item (item is `.card` in your example). E.g. If someone put `height: 200px` on an item inside a `height:300px` row flexbox, the browser shouldn't blow away that `height: 200px` with `300px`.

But because your item has `height:auto`, the item stretches.

This part of the flex spec was written before `aspect-ratio` existed. Maybe it should expand the cases where the items aren't stretched to include items that have a specified aspect-ratio and a definite main size like your example, but... it doesn't. So this is what we got :(

So, if you don't want your aspect-ratio item to stretch, you can do any of these things:

- specify a `height` on the item
- put `align-content: center` (or `start` or `end`) on the container
- put `align-items: center` (or `start` or `end`) on the container
- put `align-self: center` (or `start` or `end`) on the *item*

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the height will solve your code problem and will allow the display flex to still dictate where the card will be inside of the container. Take a look at this code.

```css
.container{
    width: 500px;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    margin: auto;
    
    display: flex;
    gap: 50px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    background: rgba(0, 1000, 0, 0.1);
    justify-content: center;
    
    align-items: center; /*To center the card vertically inside of the container*/
}

.card{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 1000, 0, 0.1);
  
    /*To center the text inside of the .card*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="card">hi</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: When you use aspect-ratio property on flex items, it may not work as expected because flexbox uses the flex property to control the size and position of flex items, rather than the width and height properties